# A proof for $\nabla |u|^p = p\ \text{sgn}(u)|u|^{p-1}\nabla u$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I believe the formula 
$$\nabla |u|^p = p\ \text{sgn}(u)|u|^{p-1}\nabla u
$$ 
to be true for $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is an open domain with nice boundary, but failed to find a good reference for this.  I am sorry if this has been asked already.

The usual assumption that I usually see regarding the chain rule for Sobolev functions, i.e.
$$
\nabla F(u) = F'(u)\nabla u,
$$
is that $F\in C^1$ with bounded derivative (or perhaps a Lipschitz function). I want $F(t)=|t|^p$, which doesn't satisfy that assumption.

My idea of the proof goes as follow: I'd like to mimic the proof of the case $p=1$ so first we show a similar result for
$$
F_\varepsilon(t) = (\varepsilon^2 + t^2)^{p/2}
$$
by approximation with $F_\varepsilon(u_n)$, where $u_n\to u$ in $W^{1,p}$ and $u_n\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. Then we take $\varepsilon \to 0$ to approximate $|\cdot|^p$. While the usual argument using the Dominated Convergence Theorem wouldn't work, I think Vitali Convergence Theorem might do the trick.

> Does anyone know a reference to this result? Also, if the formula doesn't hold in general spaces (i.e. $u\notin W^{1,p}$) then does anyone have a counterexample?

I have seen the proofs of the cases $p=1,2$. Finding a reference for a general $p\in [1,\infty)$ turns out to be a lot harder than I anticipated.

Comment: Do you know the "AC on lines" characterization of Sobolev space?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I've heard about it in my short course on Distribution Theory but I must admit that I've never read about it in detail. Would it help to put this problem in a correct perspective?

Comment: I'm a relative newcomer to Sobolev spaces myself, but shouldn't the hypotheses of the chain rule hold on any compact set? The integrability on the whole space could then be derived using Young's inequality, so $|u|^p \in W^{1,1}$.

Comment: @eepperly16 I don't understand what you meant by "the hypotheses holds on any compact set".  A function $u\in L^p$ need not be bounded.

Comment: @BigbearZzz $F$ is $C^1$ with bounded derivatives on any compact set $K$ (or Lipschitz for $K\ni 0$). Thus, without any hypotheses on the boundedness of $u$, by the chain rule for Sobolev functions, $|u|^p\in W^{1,1}(K)$ for every compact $K$ with the derivative formula as computed, so $|u|^p\in W^{1,1}_{\rm loc}(\Omega)$. Then using the formula for the derivative and Young’s inequality, you can show $\nabla |u|^p\in L^1$.

Comment: @eepperly16 $F$ is a real valued function $F:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ which is used to composed with $u:\Omega\to\Bbb R$. This is why I mentioned that $u$ is not bounded because the compactness of $K\subset \Omega$ does not affect $F$ in any way.

Comment: @BigbearZzz my apologies I didn’t see that $\Omega$ was bounded. Shouldn’t the ordinary chain rule as you quote it work? $F$ is Lipschitz with bounded derivative, isn’t it?

Comment: @eepperly16 $F(t) = |t|^p$ for $p>1$ is certainly not Lipschitz.

Comment: @BigbearZzz $F(t)$ is continuous everywhere and $C^1$ away from $0$, and thus Lipschitz by the mean value theorem on any bounded set. For $p<1$ it’s a different story.

Comment: @eepperly16 You're talking about _locally Lipschitz_, this is not the same as Lipschitz and does not satisfy the assumption of the theorem I mentioned. Please read what I said earlier again, I think you are confused about the domain of $F$.

Comment: @BigbearZzz, I've decided to withdraw my "answer" for the moment. As a matter of fact I overlooked the problem and relied on formal manipulations on the positive and negative part of the function $u$. Thank you for pointing out my error.

Comment: @BigbearZzz, while I was searching something for possibly rescuing my deleted wrong answer, I found this paper by Leoni and Morini, "Necessary and sufficient conditions for the chain rule in $W_\mathrm{loc}^{1,1}(\Bbb R^N; \Bbb R^d)$ and $BV_\mathrm{loc}(\Bbb R^N;\Bbb R^d)$":could this be of some help to you?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Thanks a lot, I will definitely have a look at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach is to truncate your function $F(t) = |t|^p.$ For each $M>0$ define $T_M(x) = \min\{|t|,M\}$ and consider $t \mapsto T_M(t)^p.$ This is a Lipschitz function that is piecewise $C^1,$ so the chain rule for Sobolev functions applies ($\dagger$).

Therefore if $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega),$ we have $T_M(u)^p \in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ with,
$$ \nabla (T_M(u)^p) = \mathbf 1_{\Omega_M}\,p\, \mathrm{sgn}(u) |u|^{p-1}\nabla u, $$
where $\Omega_M = \{ x \in \Omega : |u(x)| \leq M \}.$
Note that $T_M(u)^p \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ also, but we will only be able to show that the limit $|u|^p$ lies in $W^{1,1}(\Omega).$

There's a couple of ways to justify the limit as $M \rightarrow \infty,$ and the convergence result I like to use is the following:

> **Lemma**: If $f_n, f \in L^1(\Omega)$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere and $\int_{\Omega} |f_n| \,\mathrm{d} x \rightarrow \int_{\Omega} |f| \,\mathrm{d} x,$ then $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1(\Omega).$

This can be proven by reproducing the argument for the dominated convergence theorem ([see for example here for details](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-generalized-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem)).

One you have this, it's easy to see how to proceed. By monotone convergence, as $M \rightarrow \infty$ we get
$$ \int_{\Omega_M} \left|\nabla(T_M(u)^p) \right|\,\mathrm{d}x \rightarrow \int_{\Omega} p |u|^{p-1}|\nabla u| \,\mathrm{d}x \leq p \lVert u\rVert_{L^p(\Omega)}^{p-1} \lVert \nabla u \rVert_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq p\lVert u \rVert_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}^p. $$
Therefore we get $\nabla(T_M(u)^p) \rightarrow p\,\mathrm{sgn}(u)|u|^{p-1}\nabla u$ in $L^1(\Omega).$ Since $T_M(u)^p \rightarrow |u|^p$ in $L^1(\Omega),$ we get convergence in $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ and hence the result follows.

---

($\dagger$) It is generally true that if $F$ is Lipschitz and $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega),$ then $F(u) \in W^{1,p}(\Omega),$ (**added later**) but the proof of this is not obvious. They key insight is to show that if $u \in W^{1,1}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ and $A \subset \mathbb  R$ is a null set, then $\nabla u = 0$ a.e. on $u^{-1}(A).$ This means that $F'(u)\nabla u$ is defined regardless of the representative of $F'$ we choose. A proof of chain rule and the above fact can be found in the following:

> J. Serrin, D. Varberg. "A General Chain Rule for Derivatives and the Change of Variables Formula for the Lebesgue Integral." *The American Mathematical Monthly,* Vol. 76, No. 5 (May, 1969), pp. 514-520.

In our case however, we can simply write $T_M(u)^p = g(T_M(u))$ where $g : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a $C^1$ function with bounded derivative such that $g(t) = t^p$ on $[0,M].$ Then the result follows by applying the $C^1$ and absolute value cases.

Comment: Very interesting method! I am especially interested in your remark about $\nabla F(u) = F'(u)\nabla u$ for a particular representative of $F'$. Did you perhaps mean the precise representative (the one with most Lebesgue points)? May I ask where I can read more about this interesting result?

Comment: @BigbearZzz This result was more involved than I had thought, but I have found a reference and have edited my answer accordingly. It will in fact hold for any representative of $F'.$

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the following trick to solve the issue. Take two sequences of smooth functions $f_{\epsilon} \to f, g_{\epsilon} \to g$ in $L^p$, then

$$
|f_{\epsilon}|^{p-1} g_{\epsilon} \to |f|^{p - 1} g \qquad \text{ in } \ L^1.
$$

This follows (by adding and subtracting things) from the estimate:
$$
\int \big\vert |f_{\epsilon}|^{p-1} g_{\epsilon} \big\vert \le \|f_{\epsilon}\|_{L^p}^{\frac{p}{q}} \| g_{\epsilon}\|_{L^p}
$$
with $1/q +1/p = 1.$ This is Holder's inequality.

Then your result follows by taking a smooth approximation of $u$ and letting $f = u, g = \mathrm{sgn}(u) \nabla u .$

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure if I understand what you meant. Did you suggest that we approximate $u$ and $\mathrm{sgn}(u) \nabla u$ separately? If it works then wouldn't it give a very short prove to $\nabla |u| = \mathrm{sgn}(u) \nabla u$ as well ($p=1$)?

Comment: It also seems to me that Holder's inequality does not immediately implies your lemma. You would need to show first that if $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$, then $|f_n|^{p-1}\to |f|^{p-1}$ in $L^q$. Perhaps you have another simpler proof in mind?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I meant to approximate $u$ with $u_{\varepsilon} \to u$ in $W^{1,p}$ so that also $\mathrm{sgn}(u_{\varepsilon}) \nabla u_{\varepsilon}$ converges in $L^p$. Regarding the other point, no: I had no simple proof in mind.

Comment: The method I had in mind was using Vitali convergence theorem to deal with the convergence $|f_n|^{p-1}\to |f|^{p-1}$ in $L^q$ directly. May I ask out of curiosity if you have another method to deal with this convergence?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

A nice proof in Lieb and Loss's Analysis Chapter 6 (Distributions)  page 152.

Comment: I've never read this book before, thank you!